# Error: Unable to resolve image URL from source (undefined)

Tags: next.js, sanity

I'm trying to fetch the data from sanity and Im getting this error

here is the code from image.ts

```
import createImageUrlBuilder from "@sanity/image-url";
import type { Image } from "sanity";

import { dataset, projectId } from "../env";

const imageBuilder = createImageUrlBuilder({
   projectId: projectId || "",
   dataset: dataset || "",
});

export const urlForImage = (source: Image) => {
   return imageBuilder?.image(source).auto("format").fit("max").url();
};
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIVN9.png)